# Django package versions have conflicting dependencies. (emove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict)

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip

ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 10), -r requirements.txt (line 11), -r requirements.txt (line 16), -r requirements.txt (line 9) and Django==2.0.13 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested Django==2.0.13
    django-crontab 0.7.1 depends on Django>=1.8
    django-dbbackup 3.3.0 depends on Django>=1.5
    django-debug-toolbar 2.2 depends on Django>=1.11
    django-storages 1.10.1 depends on Django>=2.2
```

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit **https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies**

Comment: SOlVLVED IT BUY DOING THIS CMD

pip install <PACKAGE> --use-feature=2020-resolver